# How to deploy a winforms app that uses Entity Framework on server

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-6

I know many topics were opened  regarding this, but I am new with EF and couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

It all works great on my local machine - I succeeded connecting to the DB on the server(not my localdb) and everything is fine.

The problem is that now I want to deploy my app on another server and connect it to another DB.

I copied the release folder (with the .exe and stuff) to the server and changed all connection strings so they refer to the right DB.
but when running the app I get an error `Invalid object name 'IQC.dbo.@REL_IQCR_REPFORM'` - I can see that it still tries to use the "old" db name  `IQC`...
how can I make EF to always use the db in the connection string?

btw, I am using VS 2010

Comment: Where did you put your connection string? EntityFramewrok always stores ConnectionString in Web.config file. so you can sure what database you have used.

Comment: I am using winforms, so no web.config. instead I have an app.config file and the connection string is there.